# How does the kernel separate threads from processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

Suppose I have a browser process like Firefox, that has pid = 123. Firefox has 5 opened tabs each running in a separate thread, so in total it has 5 threads.

1. So I want to know in depth, how the kernel will separate the process into the thread to execute in `struct task_struct` or in the thread_info.
2. Like `struct task_struct` is a task descriptor of the task list.
   where does `struct task_struct` contain a reference or a link to these five threads.
3. Does the `struct thread_struct` of a process like Firefox contain reference to all the 5 thread

   **OR**

   each thread is treated like a process inside the Linux kernel.

Comment: `task_struct` contains architecture independent information about a process. `thread_info` contains architecture dependent information and the kernel stack. `task_struct` has a pointer to a `thread_info` and also from a `thead_info` you can access the `task_struct`. In linux both processes and threads are basically flavors of `task_structs`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike Windows, Linux does not have an implementation of "threads" in the kernel. The kernel gives us what are sometimes called "lightweight processes", which are a generalization of the concepts of "processes" and "threads", and can be used to implement either.

It may be confusing when you read kernel code and see things like `thread_struct` on the one hand, and `pid` (process ID) on the other. In reality, both are one and the same. Don't be confused by the terminology.

Each lightweight process has a completely different `thread_info` and `task_struct` (with embedded `thread_struct`). You seem to think that the `task_struct` of one lightweight process should have pointers to the `task_struct`s of other (userspace) "threads" in the same (userspace) "process". This is not the case. Inside the kernel, each "thread" is a separate process, and the scheduler deals with each one separately.

Linux has a system call called `clone` which is used to create new lightweight processes. When you call `clone`, you must provide various flags which indicate what will be shared between the new process and the existing process. They can share their address space, or they can each have a different address space. They can share their open files, or they can each have their own list of open files. They can share their signal handlers, or they can each have their own signal handlers. They can be in the same "thread group", or they can be in different thread groups. And so on...

Although "threads" and "processes" are the same thing in Linux, you can implement what we normally think of as "processes" by using `clone` to create processes which **do not share** their address space, open files, signal handlers, etc.

You can also implement what we normally think of as "threads" by using `clone` to create processes which **DO share** their address space, open files, signal handlers, etc.

If you look at the definition of `task_struct`, you will find that it has pointers to other structs such as `mm_struct` (address space), `files_struct` (open files), `sighand_struct` (signal handlers), and so on. When you `clone` a new "process", all of these structs will be *copied*. When you `clone` a new "thread", these structs will be *shared* between the new and old `task_struct`s -- they will both point to the same `mm_struct`, the same `files_struct`, and so on. Either way, you are just providing different flags to `clone` to tell it what to copy, and what to share.

I just mentioned "thread groups" above, so you might wonder about that. In short, each "thread" in a "process" has its own PID, but they all share the same TGID (thread group ID). The TGIDs are all equal to the PID of the first program thread. Userspace "PIDs", like those shown in `ps`, or in `/proc`, are actually "TGIDs" in the kernel. Naturally, `clone` has a flag to determine whether a new lightweight process will have a new TGID (thus putting it in a new "thread group") or not.

UNIX processes also have "parents" and "children". There are pointers in a Linux `task_struct` which implement the parent-child relationships. And, as you might have guessed, `clone` has a flag to determine what the parent of a new lightweight process will be. It can either be the process which called `clone`, OR the *parent* of the process which called `clone`. Can you figure out which is used when creating a "process", and which is used when creating a "thread"?

Look at the manpage for `clone`; it will be very educational. Also try `strace` on a program which uses pthreads to see `clone` in use.

(A lot of this was written from memory; others should feel free to edit in corrections as necessary)

Comment: Awesome Alex! this answered several questions I had all in one shot :)